# Troubleshooting tips for USMT?

Tags: windows, migration, user-management, troubleshooting

We have a large Vista migration underway and are using USMT (User State Migration Tool) to grab profiles in preparation for the push, which has resulted in some problems.
The majority of the captures proceed smoothly however a significant minority fail with some quixotic errors, this is typical:

```
Info                  [0x080000] CopyStream: Can't copy streams from {"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\060812-F-3108S-103.jpg"} to {"45"} object. Error 112. Exception class UnBCL::IOException: unable to write to FileStream.
enum Mig::SendObjectResult __thiscall Mig::CMediaManager::SendObjectInternal(class UnBCL::Stream *,const unsigned short *,const unsigned short *,int)
void __thiscall UnBCL::FileStream::Write(const unsigned char *,int,int)

Info                  [0x000000] Report problem is called
Info                  [0x000000] Unable to process object C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\060812-F-3108S-103.jpg -> 45, retries left = 3
Info                  [0x0802e6] Notification result: Retry.
```

....a bit later that becomes:

```
Error                 [0x0802e9] CopyStream: Can't copy streams from {"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\060812-F-3108S-103.jpg"} to {"45"} object. 
Error 112. Exception class UnBCL::IOException: unable to write to FileStream.
enum Mig::SendObjectResult __thiscall Mig::CMediaManager::SendObjectInternal(class UnBCL::Stream *,const unsigned short *,const unsigned short *,int)
void __thiscall UnBCL::FileStream::Write(const unsigned char *,int,int)

Error                 [0x0802f1] Failed to store object "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\060812-F-3108S-103.jpg", stream = "default". User aborted operation.
Error                 [0x08030a] MigDoMigration caught exception: class Mig::CAbortException: User aborted Send operation..
void __thiscall Mig::CMediaManager::SendCatalogEntry(class Mig::CCatalogEntry *)
```

...finally culminating in:

```
Info                  [0x000000] USMT error Code (status) = 11
```

[Error code 11](http://blogs.technet.com/deploymentguys/archive/2009/01/14/usmt-error-codes.aspx) corresponds to

```
USMT_UNABLE_DOMIGRATION  (A file is in use)
```

which does not seem to track with any activity occuring on the machine.

I've found the Microsoft documentation extremely unhelpful on diagnosing problems such as this and was wondering what tips other admins might have on troubleshooting USMT issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this post from the USMT Tean Blog [How to debug a USMT log like a Pro](http://blogs.technet.com/usmt/archive/2008/05/22/how-to-debug-a-usmt-log-like-a-pro.aspx). They walk you through how to debug a log and cover off a very similar problem. The error they work on is the Error 112 which maps to "There is not enough space on the disk." which is what you are also getting.

In that particular case it turned out to be not running out of space, as alfred mentioned, but that the USB drive was formatted as FAT32 and not NTFS and couldn't handle single files larger than 4GB.

From [USMT 4.0 Return Codes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd823291%28WS.10%29.aspx) you can up the USMT logging as well:

> As a best practice, we recommend that
>   you set the highest verbosity level,
>   /v:13, on the ScanState and LoadState
>   command lines, so that the most
>   detailed reporting is available in the
>   ScanState and LoadState logs.

Not that I want to send you away from SeverFault but you might also want to check out [myITforum.com](http://www.myitforum.com/) as they have some really good coverage on USMT, SCCM, SMS, SCOM, MDT etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have this error when I have my HDD full.

Check NTFS autorizations (system account too), Quota volume, ...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it has to do with the path being too long or malformed in some way? I've never had a problem with USMT yet, so...